# The following Table code does not execute in IEEE transaction Template. Please help

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
%\caption{Smart home appliances classification and parameters.}
\centering
\tablesize{\small}
\label{appliance_parameters}
%\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
 \toprule
 \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Categories }}&\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Type}}& \textbf{Power rating (kW) }&\textbf{Start time (hours)}& \textbf{End time (hours) }& \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{LOT (hours)}}\\
 & &\textbf{Rating (kWh)}&\textbf{Time (h)}&\textbf{Time (h)}\\
 \midrule
 %1.14\\0.083\\1.666\\0.1\\1.4\\1.32\\2.4\\0.225\\2.4\\0.8\\2\\0.15\\0.011\\0.005\\0.055\\1.8\\1.2
\multirow{13}{*}{Shiftable Appliances}
 &Washing Machine & 1.4 & 6 & 10 & 1--3\\
%\hhline{~-----}
 &Dish Washer & 1.32 & 15 & 20 & 1--3\\
 &Hair Straightener & 0.055 & 18 & 8 & 1--2\\
 %\hhline{~-----}
 &Hair Dryer & 1.8 & 18 & 8 & 1--2\\
 \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem here is very similar to your old question with my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485086/16550 Where do you have the command `\tablesize` from? It is undefined, in this and your last question of tables I already mentioned it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \tablesize
               {\small}
```

just use `\small`

Then you get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \multirow
```

so add the `multirow` package.

Then you get no error (but is still too wide even at `\small`)